# Android Studio and Phone have different signatures

Tags: android, signature

I am trying to run an app from android studio onto my phone after doing some updates, and am receiving the message:

"The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?"

I really do not want to uninstall because the app has months of data entered - I do not want to loose this.
Note that this app has never been published to the play store, so it doesn't seem that is the problem
Please can someone help me with this dilemma
Thanks

Comment: Did you reinstalled android studio?

Comment: Yes, re-installed - I had a service done on my computer - not sure if this has something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one solution that you don't have to remove the installed applicaiton.

You can change application id then it's gonna be installed like another application.

You should change applicationId in build.gradle(app)

Comment: If I do that the existing data won't be in the new app tho??

Comment: Yes, you can't share the data from your intalled app. If you want it, you should try to find another way for replicate all data for backup.

Comment: I have no idea how to do a backup. I may just need to start from scratch

Comment: For example, I think you installed the app for debug. Then you can copy all from the sandbox. Then do it and put all the data to your new app's sandbox. It might works well in some case. But it's not a perfect way to move all data. It's just one kind of thing you can move the data.